Dynamic Feature Module Download Affecting Cold Start Time
I am using SplitInstallManager's startInstall to download dynamic feature modules. I noticed that the cold start time of the app significantly increased.
To mitigate this, I delayed the download task to 10 minutes after the cold start. However, the cold start metrics still deteriorated. I also tried the deferredInstall API, but it did not help either.
I suspect that SplitCompat.install triggers some I/O-related logic that negatively impacts the cold start metrics since it is the only logic executed during the cold start phase. After reviewing the relevant APIs, I couldn't find any explanation.
Does anyone have a good solution for this issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
